# How to solve error DARK0283 - dark.exe : WiX

Tags: wix

When I decompile .msm file I get that kind of error:

dark.exe : error DARK0283 : Error writing to the path: 'FTTrendXMM.wxs'. Error message: 'Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\FTTrendXMM.wxs' is denied.'

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Of course, after the -x flag, it gives a different path than bin folder, so I don't know why he tries to get access to the wix source file in the binary folder

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem, instead:

```
.\dark.exe name.msm -x <output_path>
```

I used:

```
.\dark.exe name.msm <output_path>\outSourceFile.wxs
```